# Which library to link for boost::hash_combine

Tags: boost, linker

I want to use boost::hash_combine in my project. However, I was unable to find the boost library that contains this function (the library libboost_functional does not exist). I am running Arch. Is it possible that I do not have all libraries installed?

Edit:

As sehe pointed out, including the right header was the key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

int main() {
    int x = 100;
    int y = 10;

    size_t h = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(h, x);
    boost::hash_combine(h, y);

    std::cout << h << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luke 24:5:

> “Why do you look for the living among the dead?"

Most of boost is header-only. There's nothing to link. In the case of hash-combine, everything is templates so there's nothing that could be hidden from the header file.